# How to apply color dynamically in a header text box on Tablix SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I did a ssrs report using Tablix Matrix control. I am designing that matrix with one column and many rows. That once column will repeat based on the group that i had from SP at run time. It works fine. But now I want to change the background color dynamically for the header text box of the tablix. Is it possible?

I need to do dynamically. Since I dont know how many column will get at run time. It depends upon the data from Stored Procedure.

Can any one help me out this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background color for the textbox to an expression, just like any other text box. For example, something like this:

```vb
=Iif(Fields!MyHeader.Value = "AlertColumn", "#FF0000", "#FFFFFF")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old post. But I can say that yes we can achive alternate row/Column background color on Matrix control.
Please take a look into [Matrix row/column background color](http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2012/10/alternate-columnrow-color-in-matrix.html) thred.